# How to remove keyboard from textview when uiview is clicked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to remove the keyboard when it is in editing mode of a textview.I have added tap gesture on the main view.But on the click of when editing mode is for textfield then keyboard is removed but when editing mode is for textview then keyboard is not removed.Please tell me how can i tackle this issue?

**added tap gesture to the main view.**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.main_view setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
    [self.main_view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
```

**calling method**

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if([self.txt_username isFirstResponder])
    {
        [self.txt_username resignFirstResponder];
    }
    if([self.txt_password isFirstResponder])
    {
        [self.txt_password resignFirstResponder];
    }

}
```

I have already set the delegate for text view & also i have added the textview protocol.

Comment: @deepal kumar , Try my answer now, i have edited , I tried, It works perfectly

Comment: did you find the solution??, If not let me know will try to solve your issue

Comment: try my answer now I have updated it, I tried it

Answer (score 0):

delete code for set setUserInteractionEnabled =true , u not need that

and add this in your func

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

or u can use library TPKeyboardAvoiding , set for scrollview..its automatic close keyboard when u tap view..so u not need that UITapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
[[self view] endEditing:YES];
```

}

When there are new or changed touches for a given phase, the app object calls one of these methods. Each method takes two parameters: a set of touches and an event.

For more info [Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think you just put only `textview resingFirstresponder`.

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
        [self.txt_username resignFirstResponder];
}
```

use it.